# CreateWindow could not find window class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, atl, wtl, createwindow

Am using `CreateWindow()` API which was working correctly on VS2015 before upgrading to VS2019. After upgrading to VS2015 CreateWindow API is returning null HWND. Calling `AtlAxWinInit()` before `CreateWindow()` API as shown below:

```
CreateControl()
{
    AtlAxWinInit();
    HWND hwndChild =   CreateWindow(_T("AtlAxWin"),
    _T("test"),
    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,
    0,0,0,0,
    hwnd,NULL,
    ::GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);
}
```

`GetLastError()`  is returning 1407 error code which is `ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS`:

> Cannot find window class.

Could you please help me to resolve this..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

The ATL window class name was changed in the different versions of Visual Studio. It is "`AtlAxWin140`" for VS 2019.

The `atldef.h` file defines the current version of the windows class name in the following macro: `ATLAXWIN_CLASS`

You should use the `ATLAXWIN_CLASS` macro instead of _T("AtlAxWin").